# Excel Macro for Selected Area Concatenation

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping someone would have some insight as to how to approach the following Excel macro requirement.

Starting condition:
Variable number of text values in Column A.

Proposed solution:
I would like to be able to select a *variable* number of **consecutive** cells in column A, and then have the text concatenated, separated by a comma and , into a single column adjacent to the top most cell in column B.

Examples: 
A2-A4 would be selected on the sheet.
After running the macro, the contents of **B2** (Directly adjacent to top of selection) would contain text in the form "A2, A3, A4".

A5-A10 selected:
After running the macro, the contents of **B5** (Directly adjacent to top of selection) would contain text in the form "A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10".

What is killing me is how to utilize the variablity of multiple selections and additonally, I'm not clear on how to handle looping in Excel macro's. I have a CS degree but I ended up working in Infrastructure so I'm a bit rusty. Is someone could help, this would save me emmense time everyday. Thanks to any responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does what you seek.  I have not added many comments because I am not sure what level of comments are appropriate.  For example, I do not want to explain the purpose of each statement if your CS degree allows you to guess. I also suspect there is more to your question than the obvious.  For example, should I have made this a function with the worksheet and row numbers passed as parameters.  Please come back with questions and I will improve my answer as necessary.

```
Option Explicit
Sub JoinCells()

  Dim ColFirst As Long
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim JoinedValue As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowFirst As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  RowFirst = Selection.Row     ' First row of selection
  ' Selection.Rows.Count returns the number of rows in the selection.
  ' Warning! You can fool this code by making multiple selections.
  RowLast = RowFirst + Selection.Rows.Count - 1

  ColFirst = Selection.Column
  ColLast = ColFirst + Selection.Columns.Count - 1

  If ColFirst <> 1 Or ColLast <> 1 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select a range within column ""A""", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  With Worksheets("xxxxxxx")      ' Worksheet of your choice.

    JoinedValue = .Cells(RowFirst, "A").Value
    For RowCrnt = RowFirst + 1 To RowLast
      JoinedValue = JoinedValue & "," & .Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value
    Next
    .Cells(RowFirst, "B").Value = JoinedValue

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tony, this works perfect. Thank you. One question. How do I pass the current selection (highlighted cells) on the worksheet to the code so that I can set RowFirst and RowLast by selecting A2 to A9 on the sheet and executing the Macro with a shortcut key combo? I'm assuming you would have to pass the values in a function as arguements, but I dont know the function used to identify selected cells.

Comment: I have updated the macro for what I think is the easiest way of identifying the current selection.

Comment: Outstanding. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I wish I could bump your rating.

Comment: Welcome.  I got 15 points off you.  "Every little helps" as one of supermarket chains says at every opportunity.

Comment: @SiddharthRout.  Thank you for the +1 but compared with your beautiful answers I am almost ashamed to post this.